# People got pissed by cheap beer

Tags: word-choice, british-english

...and people got pissed by cheap beer.

I want to say that people got totally drunk by cheap beer.

Can I use "...and people got pissed by cheap beer."?

Comment: You get drunk _on_ beer, not _by_ it.

Comment: Pissed by (short for pissed off by) means annoyed by.

Comment: @Peter not in BrE surely? Pissed mean drunk, and pissed *off* means annoyed.

Comment: In British English, you get pissed (drunk) **on** alcoholic beverages, and **pissed off by** something that makes you angry or annoyed.

Comment: @WeatherVane, In Australia I have heard pissed (without the off) used to mean annoyed. eg He was really pissed by what you did. I can't be definitive about BrE.

Comment: I think, that Kate Bunting and Michael Harvey have solved my problem. You have to use the preposition "on" with pissed. >>> "He got pissed on cheap wine."  I love this website!!!

Comment: You might want to be careful how you are using the word.  It is colloquial and is a slightly rude word. Pissed is not a word that you would use in front of your Gran.

Comment: It sound like a sort pun to me.

Comment: @WeatherVane 'pissed' for 'pissed off' is commonly used in the UK. It may be that we imported it but it's been around for years. It is often used to express general annoyance, though, without there being a single identifiable cause which gets confusing when we say "He's feeling pissed at the moment" as there might or might not be alcohol involved. You'd need context to be sure.

Comment: You can say what you like. It is for others to judge whether or not you are uncouth, but not a matter for this list as you would see if you read the [tour].